# How can I delete only one of the table elements, because if I click it, it will delete any of the entries

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

Here is my Code

```
<?php
require '../db/dbcon.php';
$sql="SELECT ClientId,Email,FirstName,LastName,Password,PhoneNumber,AdressID from client;";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
foreach($sth as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Password']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    $clientid=$row['ClientId'];
    echo "<form action=\"viewclients.php\" method=\"post\"> ";
    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"fshij\" value=\"Fshij\"></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    if(isset($_POST['fshij'])){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM client WHERE ClientId=".$clientid.";";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        header('location:viewclients.php');
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

After the results are shown in the Webpage, if I click delete in any of these entries it will delete all of them.

Comment: as you are executing delete query inside loop

Comment: If `isset($_POST['fshij'])` validates to true, it will run the delete on every single iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I click it"

Comment: + your `header('location:viewclients.php');` won't work as expected, unless you have started output buffering, since you've already echoed stuff.

Comment: if have a delete for any table entry but it deletes all of them and I want to fix it. How can I do it?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['fshij'])) is if(isset($_POST['delete'])) to make the button click action

Comment: Are you using PDO or MYSQLI

Comment: You put a delete statement inside a loop of all your database records, what did you think would happen? You need to make your form post the id that you want to delete, and then delete only that record.

Answer (score 1):

Start by placing the value of the ClientId in the button value.

Then move the delete code up to the top of the script, and outside the loop.

```
<?php
require '../db/dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['fshij'])){

    // use a parameterised query here as you are passing user data
    // to this query
    $sql = "DELETE FROM client WHERE ClientId=?";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    // if MYSQLI
    $sth->bind_param("i", $_POST['fshij']);
    $sth->execute();

    // if PDO        
    $sth->execute(array($_POST['fshij']));

    header('location:viewclients.php');
}

$sql="SELECT ClientId,Email,FirstName,LastName,
            Password,PhoneNumber,AdressID 
            from client";
// you could have done this query using ->query() as there are no parameters to prepare
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
foreach($sth as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Password']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<form action=\"viewclients.php\" method=\"post\"> ";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='fshij' value='{$row['ClientId']}'>";

    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can leave comments, but dont edit an answer to add a thankyou